# Wrong RTL Layout in HTML - CSS override doesn't work

Tags: html, css, overriding, right-to-left

somehow the CSS overrides (left|right) under dir="rtl" don't seem to work.

To verigy - in Chrome / Firebug: only when disabling the "left" attribute, the overriding "left" (under .dir_rtl #main_search_wrapper) style starts affecting the actual layout.

Looks like a common browsers bug?

Here's a live example of the code below: http://jsfiddle.net/DwRLz/

```css
#main_search_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.dir_rtl #main_search_wrapper {
  left: 0;
  /* <-- This should override the above style */
}
```

```html
<body class="dir_rtl" dir="rtl">
  <div id="main_search_wrapper" style="display: inline-block;">
    This should be aligned to the left.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not override, just add. Your div got `left: 0;` AND `right: 0;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`left` doesn't necessarily override `right`, it will use *both* properties, basically setting them like so:

```
.dir_rtl #main_search_wrapper {
   right: 0;
   left: 0;  /* <-- This wont override the above style */
}
```

Try this:

```
.dir_rtl #main_search_wrapper {
    right: 0; 
    right: auto;   /* <-- This will override the above style for "right" */
}
```

Comment: Thank you! What I did was not overriding but adding a new attribute, that's why it didn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[bdo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bdo)** tag if you want to align text left.

```html
<bdo dir='rtl'>
   ךלחיעכגדש(&#x202b;This text will go right-to-left.)ךלחיעכגדשךלחיעכגדשךלחיעכגדש
</bdo>
```